# Mapquest, is apiKey important?

Tags: android, api-key, mapquest

I try to use MapQuest map lib to show my location, I see that in example are set

```
android:apiKey="aa"
```

And apps work on my phone to..

Can someone explain why apiKey is set, and are important to get apiKey if map work this way?
And one more question,is legal and free to use MapQuest in application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Mapquest Website](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/android-maps-api):

> If a valid MapQuest key is used, licensed data and services will be used. If no key is passed, open data and services will be used.

For a detailed description on the differences between the licensed and open data, a good summary is available [on this website](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/tools/getting-started/platform/licensed-vs-open) .

Further please refer to the [Terms of Use](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/terms-of-use) to get an understanding of how the API may be used.

I have used the open data (without an API key) in a reverse geocoding application and it works good enough. They provided some samples with the API which might be of interest, see step 5 on the [Android Maps API page](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/android-maps-api).